# Ubuntu 12.04 slow reply to nmap

Tags: nmap, ubuntu-12.04

We've upgraded some of our servers to 12.04 recently, and i've noticed that when I run nmap from some other server to check open ports on these 12.04 servers it take WAY longer than before. is this a known issue?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? Are there any new firewall rules or IDS?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. You are right, it seems that nmap runs slower when all ports are filtered than when even one port is not filtered. I wonder why is that?

Comment: I'll make it an answer then ;)

Comment: what's the difference between 1000 filtered ports and 999 filtered ports that makes it so much slower?...

Comment: I haven't got an idea, what port did you leave out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When port filtering is enabled, nmap can run a lot slower than normal.

Answer (score 1):

Nmap can adjust its timing based on round-trip times and expected responses. A port is considered filtered if no response is received within some time period. If Nmap finds a port open early in the scan, it can reduce the timeout for considering a port filtered, speeding up the rest of the scan. This is why a host with 1 open (or 1 closed) and 999 filtered ports can take significantly less time to scan than one with 1000 filtered ports.